# How to type assignment using Object.keys in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, valtio

Following is a store using Valtio, That thing works as expected but need way to type-hint this.
The goal is to create store that will hold an object & allows to update any value/ values by using action method, while not requiring to define action methods for every use case.

I have a problem with the type check in the below code:

```js
import { proxy } from 'valtio';

type PaymentStore = {
  loading: boolean;
  token: string | null;
  id: string | null;
  initialized: boolean;

  total: number;
  processing: boolean;
  paid: boolean;

  isError: boolean;
  errMsg: null | string;
};

const defaultValues: PaymentStore = {
  loading: false,
  token: null,
  id: null,
  initialized: false,

  total: 0,
  processing: false,
  paid: false,

  isError: false,
  errMsg: null,
};

const paymentStore = proxy<PaymentStore>(defaultValues);

const paymentActions = {
  setProperty<T extends keyof PaymentStore>(key: T, value: PaymentStore[T]) {
    paymentStore[key] = value
  },

  setProperties<T extends Partial<{[k in keyof PaymentStore]: PaymentStore[k]}>>(values: T) {
    Object.keys(values).forEach((valueKey) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      paymentStore[valueKey] = values[valueKey]; // >>> how to type this line?
    })
  }
}

// getting excellent aut-complete in following methods
paymentActions.setProperty('loading', false);
paymentActions.setProperties({
  loading: true,
  isError: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paymentStore[valueKey] = values[valueKey];
```

You have 2 problems with the above line of code:

1. `paymentStore[valueKey]` is a dynamic value, so we don't know the type of that field beforehand with `PaymentStore` only. You have to assign `paymentStore` variable with `Record<keyof PaymentStore, unknown>`. `unknown` in this context is to tell the type check that you don't know the type for now but you know the key is a part of `PaymentStore`
2. `typedKey` in `values[typedKey]` is a string because of `forEach` params. Therefore, you can not match `keyof PaymentStore` with `string`. You have to assert that type with `as keyof PaymentStore`

You can try the below approach with some comments in the code

```
import { proxy } from 'valtio';

type PaymentStore = {
  loading: boolean;
  token: string | null;
  id: string | null;
  initialized: boolean;

  total: number;
  processing: boolean;
  paid: boolean;

  isError: boolean;
  errMsg: null | string;
};

const defaultValues: PaymentStore = {
  loading: false,
  token: null,
  id: null,
  initialized: false,

  total: 0,
  processing: false,
  paid: false,

  isError: false,
  errMsg: null,
};

//make sure the key is a part of PaymentStore and the value can be unknown because we cannot determine the type before the value assignment
const paymentStore: Record<keyof PaymentStore, unknown> = proxy<PaymentStore>(defaultValues);

const paymentActions = {
  setProperty<T extends keyof PaymentStore>(key: T, value: PaymentStore[T]) {
    paymentStore[key] = value
  },

  setProperties<T extends Partial<PaymentStore>>(values: T) {
    Object.keys(values).forEach((valueKey) => {
      //valueKey type is a string by default due to `forEach`, so we need to assert that type for PaymentStore
      const typedKey = valueKey as keyof PaymentStore
      paymentStore[typedKey] = values[typedKey];
    })
  }
}

// getting excellent aut-complete in following methods
paymentActions.setProperty('loading', false);
paymentActions.setProperties({
  loading: true,
  isError: true,
});
//test case
paymentActions.setProperties({
  loading: 'test', //not working because loading is a boolean
  total: 'test', //not working because total is a number
  isError: true,
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-C0LB63WahlmVMQ4AAA3IyjqLk7NLAgU1OAEdhYlZdTfTuQV2XIeB+M4cj00rKM0I4kMllMxReJfBimN5ZdVws+9Tms28YMzU5T3s3jnykRCApdBymIvTxZGwFt30YbBqSpOBVBHGg1CAop3COXkXBgABaeZwH0W1QnwPR5F1fx+HZCBQMYO8hF7ftFjw78xwgCdWBrYhLmUNRiGzAk2wa3zmtoVr2t-CDihrdi5AUfrRhsXZflaDouk0FbMVipgaVtJZVTuUaM3Gjs2pHDquuAWb5r665iAOmBBq4qkrVNaBTFE+N1hNe6Mp5PkKkSAQIXSEgnpeml3t1T7vqNE1UioQTeUCLIchCdbcW6VkoFWhK2yAA)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it solves the problem, unfortunately introduced another issue, With Valtio & react sometimes we need to access the value from the store directly (proxy), like this `const totalValue = paymentStore.total; // unknown` In that case all values are type `unknown` which is unexpected. Is there any way to keep type safety on that?

Comment: You can cast the type `const paymentStoreValue = paymentStore as PaymentStore; const totalValue = paymentStoreValue.total;` because we know `Record<keyof PaymentStore, unknown>` is `PaymentStore` @Md.A.Apu